# Error while printing crystal report, with that exception message "No printers are installed"

Tags: asp.net, deployment, crystal-reports, web-deployment-project

I got an exception with message "No printers are installed." while printing a report for depolyed release of our website.
I use `_rptDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);` to print a report.

I got that exception, even I've more than one printer installed on my machine.
Also, I don't get that exception while development, everything while development is going fine.

I used "Publish Web Site" and "Web Project Deployment" options to publish/deploy website, but I got the same result.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Sample Code

```
DataSet dsResult = null;
rptDocument = new ReportDocument();
rptDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("WINGR0040.rpt"));

// Fetch report data.
...

rptDocument.SetDataSource(dsResult);

// Print report.
rptDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Can you print this report if you use any of the Crystal Report Viewer controls?

Are you trying to print the report on the server?

Comment: No, I cannot print report using Crystal Report viewer. I tried to print the report, on the server, and on the client, but I got the same result as I described.

Comment: ActiveX solutions won't solve that issue, as client may use any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really export the report to PDF so the user prints at their desktop printer. However maybe the Print Spooler Service is stopped on the iis server so crytsal is confused.

Comment: Export report to PDF will solve the issue, but that solution is not acceptable for customer. Using print button should print document directly, no need to export to it, he said.

Comment: For you to print from the server, is a security risk since by default the account iis uses for the app domains is restricted. Also this will **only** work in an intranet setting.

Comment: What does this mean? "Also this will only work in an intranet setting"?

Comment: is IIs user need specific permission for Print Spooler Service?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a printer on the Web server under the user account that site runs under?

Have you tried setting the printer name first?

```
Report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerName;
```

If your site runs under an account e.g DOMAIN\WebService you need to ensure that this user account has a default printer.

You could also try setting the printer name like this:

```
Report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = this.printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
```

This will get the default printer.

This [article](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/communitycs/TechnicalPapers/crnet_web_app_printing.pdf) may help you get this working.

EDIT:

This article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225384(VS.80).aspx) describes how printing can be acheived using Crystal Reports and ASP.NET. If you are not implementing either of these solutions then I don't think you will be able to print client side.

The .cab file mentioned in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225384(VS.80).aspx) link can be found here:

[Visual Studio 2005](http://support.businessobjects.com/CRforVS2005/PrintControl.cab)
or
[Visual Studio 2008](http://support.businessobjects.com/CRforVS2008/PrintControl.cab)

Without you posting further code and more detail as to how you are generating the report I don't I am going to be able to fully answer your question.

Thanks

Comment: Website is published on another server rather than client machine.
For printer, both web server and client's machine have an installed printer.

Comment: Under the user account that the site runs? Also, this will print it from the server NOT the client. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, I need to print report from client machine?  
For this, "Under the user account that the site runs?" do you mean that I should give certain permissions for every client machine, or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The PrintDocument and PrinterSettings are for Windows Form projects only, or I missing something?

Comment: The title of the article is `Printing Web based reports with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio .NET`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve the problem. My issue, that I need to print report from client machine using his machine printer, not server printer!

Comment: Have you noticed this in link you have posted?

Note: Only Internet Explorer supports ActiveX controls. Printing from a non-Internet Explorer client (FireFox, Safari, Mozilla, and others) reverts to the PDF export dialog.

Sure, this is the case I've, so this solution will not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I dont found a way to print by client-side.

There go how works to me by server-side:

on Page_Load i got this:

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(printer);
}
```

Now on button_click:

```
var dsTela = (DataSet)Session["dsTela"];

var cr = new ReportDocument();

var rpt = Request.QueryString["nomeRel"];
cr.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Crystal/" + rpt));

    //----------Crystal Reports---------------//

    // carrega o reltório
cr.SetDataSource(dsTela);

System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();

printerSettings.PrinterName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

cr.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, new PageSettings(), false);
```

//this one works for me

If your printer don`t show in your server-side, try this one:

Source: (https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;184291)

To enable IIS to enumerate the network printers by using the SYSTEM account, follow these steps.

Note If the process is running under the Network Service account, explicit permissions to the newly created registry are required.

1. Make sure that you are currently logged in to the server as a user who has the desired network printers installed.
2. Start Registry Editor.
3. Click the following key:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections
4. On the Registry menu, click Export Registry File.
5. In the File Name box, type c:\printconns.reg.
6. To open the printconns.reg file in Notepad, click Start, click Run, type Notepad printconns.reg in the Open box, and then click OK.
7. Replace the text HKEY_CURRENT_USER with the text HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT.
8. Save the file.
9. To import the file into the registry, double-click the file in Windows Explorer.
10. Restart the Print Spooler service.